# double integral calculation $ \iint\frac{\cos(2y)}{\sqrt{9-4\sin^2x}} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: integration

Calculate the double integral:

$$ \iint_R\frac{\cos(2y)}{\sqrt{9-4\sin^2x}} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$
where $R:=\left\{(x,y)\mid 0\le x\le y,\, 0\le y\le\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right\}$. I changed the order of integration to dydy and my new limits for y are 0 to x, and for x are pi/2 to 0. I get a negative answer. Is it possible to have a negative answer, and is it possible to have limits going from pi/2 to 0?

Comment: You should specify what your limits are now...

Comment: What domain? A first tip if the domain is a square is that your function is a product of a function depending on $x$ and a function depending on $y$.

Comment: I feel obligated to vote to close this question unless it's edited to include a region of integration, since without it the question impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the order of integration, so that the integral looks like

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2} dy \int_0^y dx \frac{\cos{2 y}}{\sqrt{9-4 \sin^2{x}}} &= \int_0^{\pi/2} dx \int_x^{\pi/2} dy \frac{\cos{2 y}}{\sqrt{9-4 \sin^2{x}}} \\ &= -\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \frac{\sin{x} \cos{x}}{\sqrt{9-4 \sin^2{x}}}\\ &= -\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{9-4 u}} \\ &=-\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{4}\end{align}$$